# How to readfile / read in python, PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, queue, signals, readfile, qthread

I have the following code in PyQT, it is doing its job properly. There is a readfile function in a QThread. I want to start a "loading" animation when it is starting to find the hostnames in the file. And I want to stop the "animation" when it went through of all of it. Hostnames comes by user input and they append in a queue ( the queue can contain multiple hostnames). What it is doing now opening and closing the file constantly and like by that the loading animation is poping up and closing rapdily. Sure there is a way to open the file once and cycle through all the hostnames instead to open it for every hostname in the queue.

**Here is the code:**

```py
class Worker2(QThread):
   found = Signal(str)
   notFound = Signal(str)
   animation = Signal()

   def __init__(self):
       QThread.__init__(self)
       self.queue = Queue()
       
   
   def run(self):
       self.keepRunning = True
       while self.keepRunning:

           hostlist = self.queue.get()
           if not self.keepRunning:
               break
           for hostname in hostlist.splitlines():
               if not self.keepRunning:
                   break
               if hostlist is None:
                   continue
               self.animation.emit()
               f = open("allhosts.txt", "r")
               if hostname in f.read():
                   self.found.emit(hostname)
               else:
                   self.notFound.emit(hostname)
           self.finished.emit()   
            
   def stop(self):
       self.keepRunning = False
       self.queue.put(None)


   def lookUp(self, hostname):
       self.queue.put(hostname)
```

Comment: Is that file so big to justify looking up in a separate thread? Do its contents change while the program is running?

Comment: Content is not changing. But the file size is around 70MB. And by the time this can expand...

Comment: Then constantly opening the file is certainly not a good idea, even if done once for each queue request. You could just load it when starting the program as a list of strings (use `f.read().split(<separator>)`: if they're one per line, use `split('\n')`): just make it an instance attribute and do a simple `if hostname in self.hostlist`, which is pretty fast since the file is already in memory. As an alternative, assuming the file doesn't need to be manually modified, using sqlite is certainly a better option for both memory and performance, and allows better maintenance.

Comment: Ok! I will do it like that.